# Using AES-256-CBC encryption from github

Tags: java, maven, github, encryption

I would like to use these classes
https://github.com/fukata/AES-256-CBC-Example
in my project, but even if I compile it w/o changing anything it causes error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size   at
>   AESUtil.encrypt(AESUtil.java:23)  at AESMain.main(AESMain.java:10)
>   Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size    at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1039)     at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)     at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)   at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1396)    at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)    at
>   AESUtil.encrypt(AESUtil.java:20)  ... 1 more

How to fix *Illegal key size*?
I downloaded it and copied *java* folder to my project. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Essentially AES encryption with a key length of 128-bits is as secure as 256-bits, neither can be brute forced.

Comment: @zaph True, but I would like to use AES-256 with 32byte IV and now above classes throw error: `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long` cause I used 32byte IV

Comment: A 32-byte IV makes no sense, AES in CBC mode requires a 16-byte IV.

Comment: @J.Kennsy AES supports three key length: 128, 192 & 256 bits and **one IV length**, the same as the block size: 128-bits (16-bytes).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would need to install the Java Cryptography Unlimited Strength extensions:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Comment: Well, instruction says that I should paste both jars to <java_home>/lib/security folder, but mine doesn't exists there (I have jdk, but it doesn't change anything I guess).

Comment: @J.Kennsy for JDK the jre directory is _under_ the jdk directory, so it's jdk[version]/jre/lib/security . Note the unlimited-policy is different per Java version which you didn't identify; for 8 use http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html -- and for 9, at last, it isn't needed.